# Array Declaration-Error in Java

Tags: java

Why

```
int arr[][]=new int[5][];
```

declaration is perfectly fine  but

```
int arr[][]=new int[][5]
```

generates compile time error ?
Please do help me. I am not able to understand why is that so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int arr[][]` (which is more typically written as `int[][] arr`) is an array, each element of which is in turn a reference to an array.

`new int[][5]` would mean "create an array of unknown length, each element of which is a reference to an array, each of length 5".  Obviously, that doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, `new int[5][]` means "create a length-5 array, each element of which is a null reference to an array".